# How do I open Starcraft using custom .mpq files, in windowed mode?

Tags: starcraft

To play Starcraft in **windowed** mode I use *Chaoslauncher* with *W-Mode* plugin activated.

To play Starcraft with **mods** (opening starcraft using more .mpq files) I use *MPQDraft*.

How do I open Starcraft with custom .mpq files, in windowed mode? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download http://winner.cspsx.de/Starcraft/Tool/InfectedStarcraft.zip
- Unpack them into the starcraft directory
- Edit `InfectedStarcraft.exe.injlist` to contain those dlls you want to inject (at least `wmode.dll`)
- Run `InfectedStarcraft.exe` instead of the normal `Starcraft.exe`. While using MPQDraft, click to browse and target `InfectedStarcraft.exe`.

You can't join battle.net while using this technique. The integrity check will reject it with the usual "check if you have a virus" message. ICCup without antihack should work.

There's also the latest version of W-Mode (1.02) which includes doublesize mode:

> Scale to double the native resolution (640x480 => 1280x960) with no interpolation

- Download http://winner.cspsx.de/Starcraft/Tool/scloader2b_wmode_102.zip
- Replace the current `wmode.dll` with the new one from this zip.

Comment: "The program can't start because storm.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I copied the storm.dll from Starcraft's directory to the extracted folder of infectedStarcraft, and then says "LoadLibrary failed 998", suddenly the data file error: "The problem ocurred while trying to load the file: D:\downloads\infectedstarcraft\local.dll"

Comment: After each file seems it starts to ask all the files from starcraft directory. Instead, I copied all of infected starcraft content (except the ones that asked to replace) and before the game runs it still pop up the "LoadLibrary failed 998" error.

Comment: I'd appreciate your help if you figure it out and/or being a bit more clear (or extended) about the steps..

Comment: @Fabián You need to copy all of them into the starcraft directory. I don't think it should ask to overwrite any file, not of them should exist in the SC directory. If you rename `InfectedStarcraft.exe`, you'll need to rename the `.visitor` and `.injlist` files as well.

Comment: There's no way I can find w-mode 1.02 as a dll file? Because that version includes the doublesize mode. The one that's included within the infectedStarcraft.zip doesn't.

Comment: @Fabián `.bwl` files are simply renamed `dll`s which export certain functions. AFAIR you can simply use the `wmode.bwl` shipped with Chaoslauncher with infected starcraft. Either rename it to `wmode.dll`, or add it as `path\wmode.bwl` in the `.injlist` file. When I created that infected starcraft bundle wmode 1.2 wasn't published yet, so it contains an older version.

Comment: I renamed the `infectedStarcraft.exe` to `Starcraft.exe` (saved the original), and gives me an error saying "could not load module `Starcr.exe.visitor`". So I left it like that (same to `.injlist` and `.exe` files) and it worked. Thing is the Chaoslauncher asks me for the `Starcraft.exe` to be found, doesn't accept `Starcr.exe`.

Comment: I think Chaoslauncher expects `Starcraft*.exe`, but when using chaoslauncher you don't really need infected starcraft. If you rename `InfectedStarcraft.exe` you need to rename both `.injlist` and `.visitor` to the same prefix. You can simply replace `wmode.dll` with `wmode.bwl` to get the 1.2 version.

Comment: That's like returning to the main problem: how do I load custom `mpq` files using wmode? Can chaoslauncher load mpqdraft or some sort of mpq loader?

Comment: My idea for the original problem was renaming `infectedstarcraft.*` to `Starcraft.*` (rename all three files, not just the exe) and then use whatever mod loader your like. Add `wmode.bwl` with the correct path to `starcraft.exe.injlist` if you want wmode 1.2. No need for chaoslauncher itself (only the wmode.bwl it bundles).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12110/discussion-between-fabian-and-codesinchaos)